# Using System.Windows.Forms in a Visual Studio Macro

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, visual-studio-2005, vbscript, macros

I have started writing a Macro in Visual Studio 2005 like this:

```
Public Sub myMacro()
    Dim myListBox As New System.Windows.Forms.ListBox()
    For Each x As String In xs
        myListBox.Items.Add(x)
    Next
```

But I'm completely at a loss as to how to display the `ListBox`,

I'd like behaviour similar to this InputBox example:

```
Dim str As String = InputBox("title", "prompt")
```

As we can see the `InputBox` can be constructed and displayed on the screen immediately, returning a `String` once the box is closed.

I tried called the following methods on `myListBox` after populating it with the `String`s in `xs`, but the `ListBox` still does not appear of the screen:

```
myListBox.EndUpdate()
myListBox.Show()
```

I have also tried creating a `System.Windows.Forms.Form` and adding the `ListBox` to it, following a similar approach to the one outlined for a button [here (under Examples, Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.aspx). Again nothing appears on the `form.ShowDialog()` call.

Comment: Have you added a reference to the System.Windows.Forms assembly? BTW, I think you're going to need to elaborate because I really can't see any relation between a ListBox and an InputBox prompt.

Comment: I had no added a reference but now I have, so thanks for that advice. Unfortunately the ListBox is still not displaying. To clarify, the relation to InputBox I require is only that it is displayed! Currently I cannot find a way to display the ListBox on screen. I have edited my question to clarify this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code below worked fine for me in Visual Studio 2008.  The reference to `System.Windows.Forms` was already in place when I opened up the macros IDE, I simply had to add an `Imports System.Windows.Forms` at the top of the module.

```
Public Sub myMacro()

    Dim myListBox As New ListBox
    Dim xs As String() = New String() {"First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth"}

    For Each x As String In xs
        myListBox.Items.Add(x)
    Next

    Dim frm As New Form
    Dim btn As New Button

    btn.Text = "OK"
    btn.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK

    frm.Controls.Add(btn)
    btn.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom

    frm.Controls.Add(myListBox)
    myListBox.Dock = DockStyle.Fill

    If frm.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        MessageBox.Show(myListBox.SelectedItem)
    End If

End Sub
```